# Getting fopen fail when trying to update bios

Tags: bios

I enter the shell and just use:

```
fs2:
dir
F.nsh
```

This worked when it was the efi for the EC, but for the BIOS file it is failing with:

```
goffset=0
greset=1
filename=00000000
fopen fail
```

Am I missing files that should be in on the flash drive?

[image]

Comment: Where do you see the BIOS folder? I think you need to enter `fs1:` to see it, and the file might be called `Flash.nsh`.